# struct and typedef initialization

Tags: c

I am not sure why I am not getting a display on the console for the value of maxProd. I think I am declaring the arr_integer array variable wrong in main?

I ran a couple tests and the program looks like it does not even get to call solution().

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to get this to work and get rid of the following warnings;

> Adjacent_Element_Product.c:31:40: note: (near initialization for 'array') 
> Adjacent_Element_Product.c:31:43: warning: excess elements in struct initializer

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    
    
    typedef struct arr_integer {
      int size;
      int *arr;
    } arr_integer;            
    
    arr_integer alloc_arr_integer(int len) {
      arr_integer a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(int) * len) : NULL};
      return a;
    }                                
    
    
    int solution(arr_integer inputArray) {       
    
    int maxProd = inputArray.arr[0] * inputArray.arr[1];
      for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.size - 1; i++)
      {
        int product = inputArray.arr[i] * inputArray.arr[i + 1];        //multiple next door neighbours.
        if (product > maxProd)
          maxProd = product;
      }
      
      return printf("maxProd: %d\n", maxProd);
    }
    
    
    int main()
    {
        arr_integer array = {3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3};            
        solution(array);            
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain how `alloc_arr_integer()` is used.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't allocate memory for the array and that it then tries to use the list of integers as an `int*`.

A possible remedy:

```c
#define Size(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x))

int main() {
    int ints[] = {3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3};
    arr_integer array = {.size = Size(ints), .arr = ints};
    solution(array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the relevant changes:

1. added <stdlib.h> for `malloc`
2. eliminated `alloc_arr_integer()` which was not used
3. `maxProd` is initialized to `INT_MIN` and tweaked initial loop condition to reduce duplication
4. to make the solution a little smaller passing the value inline to solution (@TedLyngmo probably gave you a better solution)

Not fixed:

5. `arr_integer` doesn't seem to add any value so maybe just pass size and array to `solution()`.  You could create a macro to initialize it using the approach @TedLyngmo shared with you.  It has to be a macro as `int []` degrades to `int *` in a function call, and the latter (silently?) gives you the wrong result which makes it error prune.
6. Does negative size make sense?  If not then use an unsigned type.
7. What is the solution if `size < 2`?
8. `solution()` returns the value from `printf()` which is strange.  You might want to return `maxProd` and have `main()` print out the value.  This makes your function testable

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct arr_integer {
    int size;
    int *arr;
} arr_integer;

int solution(arr_integer inputArray) {
    int maxProd = INT_MIN; // what is answer if size < 2?  error?
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.size - 1; i++) {
        int product = inputArray.arr[i] * inputArray.arr[i + 1];        //multiple next door neighbours.
        if (product > maxProd)
            maxProd = product;
    }
    return printf("maxProd: %d\n", maxProd);
}

int main() {
    solution((arr_integer) {
        6,
        (int []) { 3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3 }
    });
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
maxProd: 21
```